# How to disable button with materialize?

Tags: jquery, materialize

I try to disable a button in materialize without delete the click event. But as you can see on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abm8wjga/2/), I only get the visual effect. The click event is still launching.

I tried the following:

```
$('#btnOne').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
```

Is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT : it seems there isn't the problem with the tag `button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find the answer.

`a` tags cannot be disabled by properties, `button` can be used instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can add some CSS rule and keep your current jQuery code.

For example:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will prevent all the events, when that class is triggered.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abm8wjga/4/):

**NOTE:** Pointer Events is supported in most modern browsers. Check it out: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Great discovery but I prefer a solution that uses javascript sorry

Comment: No problem. @Clemzd is right. You should change your ``anchor`` to ``button``. I also now noticed that you didn't put a ``href`` attribute to the ``<a>`` which is not a good practice at all. So, stick to the ``button``.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the listener when `#disableBtnOne` is clicked -

```
$('#disableBtnOne').click(function(){
    $('#btnOne').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled').off( "click" );
});
```

See new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guktkss3/)

Comment: but what if i want to keep the function in the click event. I don't want to rebind it each time

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why jQuery cannot support in some case.
When I use this way, it work !

```
document.getElementById('yours-id').classList.add("disabled");
```

By the way, the following code is html tag of my button.

```
    <a class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-1" id="rtmp-youtube-start">YouTube Live Sync</a>
```

In this case, I'm sure it work.